# Loop thru multiple select ajax data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a multiple select item, which allows me to check multiple items. I want to send those selected items via ajax request and afterwards I want to import the those items into my database. My problem is, that I don't know how to loop thru the passed array, which I get by the POST request.

**Ajax Request**

```
function insertPlayers(){   
    var data = $("#playerCards").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/database/playercards.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
        }
    });    
}
```

**This is my HTML multiple select:**

```
<select multiple id="assignAccount" name="assignAccount" class="form-control select">
// Options inserted by JQuery later
</select>
```

**This is how my data looks like when I alert it before sending the Ajax Request:**

```
playersearch=test&buypercentage=85&assignAccount=9&assignAccount=10&assignAccount=11
```

**How I add the options to my multiple selectbox:**

```
// loop the response
$.each(response, function(i, e){
    // just use your column names, these are just an example, but you get the idea
    opt += '<option value="'+e.id+'">'+ e.email + ' - ' + e.coins + '</option>';
});
// append the markup to that select box
$('#assignAccount').html(opt)
```

**My problem:**
It should be clearly now that the assignAccount variable is a array which I want to loop thru in PHP but I don't know how I can do this because I don't know the indices. This is what I've tried:

```
$accountIds = $_POST['assignAccount'];
foreach ($accountIds as $account){
    echo $account;
}
```

Comment: you need to change the ids of the posts.  On your php page you are only going to have 3 POST variables.  playersearch=test,buypercentage=85,assignAccount=11.   Each post for assignAccount is going to over write the previous.

Comment: Ok I understand, seems like it isnt an array as I thought. What do you suggest to do it? I mean every option has its own value atm. I added a code snippet, how I add my options

Comment: on the playercards.php  do print_r($_POST).  make the name of the select field an array.  <select name='assignAccount[]' id='assignAccount[]'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the select statement multiple id an array

```
 <select name='assignAccount[]' id='assignAccount[]'>
```

on your php page you will now have an array for this post.

```
 $_POST['assignAccount'][0]
 $_POST['assignAccount'][1]
```

and so on.

Comment: but when a form is being serialized, only `name` attributes are taken into account.

Comment: I just have always done it this way.  Maybe previous jquery versions needed both name and id.  but you are correct, it would work the same to do name='assignAccount[]' i believe.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<select multiple id="assignAccount" name="assignAccount" class="form-control select">
```

to something more like

```
<select id='assignAccount' name='assignAccount[]' multiple='multiple' class='form-control select'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The select element when multiple send data like this:

```
playersearch=test&buypercentage=85&assignAccount=9,10,11
```

Hence, in the PHP side you do this:

```
$accountIds = explode(",", $_POST['assignAccount']);
foreach ($accountIds as $account){
    echo $account;
}
```